# Remove trailing period in Boxhandler package

Tags: captions, punctuation

Is there a way to remove the trailing period in the `boxhandler` package? It seems to occur with both the `bxfigure` and `bxtable` commands, but I have instances where I need no trailing periods.

Minimum Working Example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\begin{document}
\bxfigure[ht]{Figure caption will automatically have a period placed at the end}{\rule{3in}{2in}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The period is inserted manually in the code. There exists no switch to turn this functionality on/off. It could probably be done by defining a new `\make@caption` macro consisting of patches to the existing [`boxhandler`](http://ctan.org/pkg/boxhandler) macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This period is hard coded into `boxhandler.sty`. For me, this would be sufficient reason not to use this package. You coild edit that file and make changes to six of the internal caption commands:

```
\offset@caption 
\nooffset@caption
\shortleft@caption
\shortcenter@caption
\shortright@caption
\new@makecaption
```

Remove the period after `#2` in each of their definitions.

Alternatively, the following will remove the period in many cases:

```
\def\gobble#1{}
\bxfigure[ht]{Figure caption will automatically have a period 
  placed at the end\protect\gobble}{\rule{3in}{2in}}
```

This should let `\gobble` take the period as its argument and replace it with nothing.

My preference would be to edit the `boxhandler.sty`. Caveats: I can't guarantee those six commands are the only ones that add a period and I definitely can't guarantee that the `\gobble` trick will always (or even usually) work.

Comment: +1 for the remark, "For me, [the hard-coded period] would be sufficient reason not to use this package."

Comment: Thanks. I do not have many figures/tables that require no periods, but it's definitely frustrating that it is hardcoded. I'm using the package because I do have many figures and tables, and I needed a consistent way of fitting the caption width to the width of the figure/table. I know rowfloat package can be used, but it interfered with my algorithms package. Thank you again for your help.